Process names and allowed characters in Linux
I am writing a shell script to parse the output of pstree, and obtain a list of child process PIDs.

$> pstree -pct $target
zsh(<target>)─┬─bash(83639)
           ├─bash(84223)
           ├─bash(93310)───sleep(93313)
           ├─pstree(95677)
           └─zsh(94826)

A straightforward approach to get the list of PIDs is to look for things inside parentheses ( ). My only concern is strange process names which is why I was wondering if there is any documentation on how process names are defined and allowed characters.

AFAIK there's no restriction on the characters in process names. Don't try to parse output of commands like pstree, get the information from /proc.

@markp-fuso But nothing prevents an all-numeric process name. gcc foo.c -o 1234

bash(18630)─┬─1234(1234)(23140) you coud have this if the process name is 1234(1234)

Yeah, I don't think this pstree driven approach is going to work out on a system with a lot of users. I tried looking into libprocfs but ultimately found a nice bash solution

Thank you for the comments.
Ultimately, I realized that parsing the output of pstree would not be a robust solution. I instead opted for the following method
kill_children_recursive()
{
    local parent="${1}"

    if ! [ -n "$parent" ]; then # Base case for recursion
          return
    fi

    local children=$(ps -o pid= --ppid "${parent}")
    for pid in "${children}"
    do
        kill_children_recursive $pid
    done

    kill -s TERM $parent
}

kill_children_recursive $target

I would like to credit Graeme's answer.

Use positive logic as much as possible for clarity and to avoid potential double negatives: if ! [ -n "$parent" ] = if [ -z "$parent" ]. Also, always quote your variables and use an array rather than a scalar to contain children so you CAN quote them - readarray -t children < <(ps -o pid= --ppid "${parent}"); for pid in "${children[@]}"; do          kill_children_recursive "$pid"; .... Always copy/paste your scripts into http://shellcheck.net until you get more familiar with shell programming.

Thanks a lot ed! Appreciate the tips, should be super helpful for a newbie at bash :). I had run into a bunch of issues with iterating over the value of children lol
